# Reconstructing a function from derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose I need to find the form of a differentiable function $f(x)$. I know $f(0)$ and I know $f^\prime(x)$, the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$, for all $x$. Can I reconstruct the function $f(x)$ from this information?

Comment: Yes $f(x) = f(0)+\int_0^x f'(t) dt$

Comment: You should try reading about [antiderivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative). f(0) gives you the value for the constant of integration

Comment: Frequently. This is the basis of solving ordinary differential equations. In many cases, numerical methods are needed, there is no closed form solutions, e.g. $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2\cos^2 x}}$

Comment: Using the previous comments, if the indefinite integral $~\displaystyle \int f(t)dt~$ has no closed form, one artificial way of avoiding numerical approximations is to express $~\displaystyle \int_0^x f(t)dt~$ as the limit, as $~n\to \infty~$ of the corresponding [Riemann Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum).

Answer (score 0):

Under some assumptions you surely can. Here, assuming $f$ is integrable (i.e., the Riemann sums converge), you can write
\begin{align}
f(x) = f(0) + \int_{y=0}^x f'(y) \, \mathrm dy.
\end{align}
As examples of integrable functions, we know that any continuous function is integrable. Hence, any differentiable function is integrable!

Comment: If the function is differentiable on a certain interval then for sure it is integrable there.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, yes! This amounts to computing an [antiderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) or integral of $f'(x)$. In fact, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t)\, dt$$

So, for example, if one knew that a given function $f(x)$ satisfied $f'(x) = x^2$ and $f(0) = 1$, then

$$f(x) = 1 + \int_0^x t^2\, dt = 1 + \Big(\frac{1}{3}t^3\Big|_{t=0}^x\Big) = 1 + \frac{1}{3}x^3$$

Here the "evaluation bar" is a bit of notational shorthand; $f(x)\Big|_a^b = f(b) - f(a)$.

Comment: The FTC requires $f'(x)$ to be continuous.